# The mesh is not deforming properly with the armature

Tags: modeling

I have this model that I am working on and the rig is working all good except for when I go to the tail the spines of the mesh are not moving adequately with the bones causing an unusual deformation when I am raising the tail_IK bone.

[image]

Can someone help me out?

Here's the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ES5H3dzZXpqEZSAef3kAHPr8JTakaisU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to paint in Weight Paint mode to correct that, also you have inner faces, they were probably created by the Mirror modifier, remove them